# Page doesn't open the right size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was hoping someone can help me out. When I open my page I'm trying to create in Firefox it is zoomed right in. also when I open in safari it is a different layout (the col-md-1 from the left side had disappeared.) I am new to this so I'm sorry if my code is terrible or the answer is quite obvious. I have been trying a few things to fix it but nothing seems to work. thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Life Atlas</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya"   rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400i"   rel="stylesheet">

<style>
/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

a:hover { text-decoration: none; }

.topnav {
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 99;
    color: black;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-width:1px 0; 
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 20;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
}

.topnav li 
{
    display:inline;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.topnav a{
display:inline-block;
padding:50px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #BFBFBF;}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {color: black;}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
color: black;}


#title{font-family: 'Alegreya', serif;
font-size: 250px;
text-align: center;}



.stories{font-size: 50px;}

 .leftstories{font-size: 50px; display: block;}

.title-stories{font-size: 100px;
font-family: 'Lora', serif;
color: #BC9B5D;
padding-right: 100px;
padding-left: 100px;
width: 80%;}

.text-insert {text-align: justify;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-right: 100px;
padding-left: 100px;}

.right{
text-decoration: none;
 padding-bottom:0px;
 list-style: none;}

.right li{margin-top: 75px;}

.right li img{margin-top: 75px;
margin-bottom: 0px;}

.left{
text-decoration: none;
padding-bottom:0px;
list-style: none;}

.left li{margin-top: 75px;}

.left li img{margin-top: 75px;
margin-bottom: 75px;}



 @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?       family=Noto+Sans:400,700);
* {
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }



.image  {background: url(photos/main-image-web.jpg) no-repeat fixed;   background-image: no-repeat fixed;
background-position: center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
min-height: 1000px;}

.banner h1, .banner h3, .banner h6, .banner p{
  margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
 color: #7F7F7F;
  background-color: white;}

.banner {
  color: white;
  background: url(photos/mornington.jpg) top left/cover no-repeat;
  height: 2000px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;}


.banner h1{font-style: 'Lora', serif;
font-size: 100px;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
padding-left: 150px;
padding-right: 150px;}

.banner p{font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: normal;
 padding-top: 50px;}

.banner h1: hover{color: black;
 opacity: 0;}





</style>

</head>

<BODY>

<div class ="container-fluid">
<h1 id="title">Life Atlas</h1>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <ul class="topnav">
<li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
<li><a href="">TRAVEL BLOG</a></li>
<li><a href="">COLLABORATION</a></li>
<li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
 </ul>
</div></div>


<div class="image"></div>



<section class="content">
<div class="container-fluid" class="row">
<div class="col-md-1"></div>


<!-- Left Hand Column -->
<div class="col-md-5" style="margin-top:  450px">
  <ul class="left">
    <li>
      <img src="photos/USA-2.jpg" style="width: 100%" class="pull-right">
     </li>
     <li>
      <img src="photos/Bridge.jpg" style="width: 100%" class="pull-right">
      </li>
      <div class="leftstories">
     <li>
       <p style="padding-left: 100px">PHOTOGRAPHY</p>
       <h2 class="title-stories">Looking for a dedicated and loveable photographer? You're in the right place.</h2>
       <p class="text-insert">Whether it’s a relaxed family portrait session, a special event, a personal portrait session, the day you marry the love of your life; Life Atlas is dedicated to capturing beautiful passing moments and making sure that they can live forever..</p> 
      </li>
      </div>
      <li>
        <img src="photos/homepageprofile.jpg" style="width: 100%">
      </li>


    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- right hand column -->
  <div class="stories">
  <div class="col-md-5" style="padding-left: 50px">
   <ul class="right">
     <li>

      <p style="padding-left: 100px;">TRAVEL</p>
      <h2 class="title-stories">Stories from around the world</h2>
      <p class="text-insert">Journey with me around the world, across the country, and sometimes even just down the street. A compilation of stories and advice, this is the atlas of my travels, written to help improve your travels.
      This is advice straight from my heart, about all those things closest to it; adventure, photographic opportunities that take your breath away, and culinary delights that pair best with a glass of red.</p></li>
    <li>
      <img src="photos/Inspo.jpg" style="width: 100%">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="photos/event.jpg" style="width: 100%">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="photos/homepagewedding.jpg" style="width: 100%">
    </li>
      <li>
        <p style="padding-left: 100px;">PERSONAL</p>
        <h2 class="title-stories">So who is Life Atlas?</h2>
        <p class="text-insert">The more suitable question may in fact be 'what is Life Atlas'? Each of our lives are a journey, and inevitably a story. My quest as a photographer is to add to your Life Atlas; to capture moments and memories that become part of your life story.
      Life Atlas is the sum of your adventures, of my adventures. It is the every growing and ever evolving story of who I am, what I seek, how I work, where I've travelled and who I've met along the way.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="banner">
    <div class="banner-text"><a href="">
      <p>READ MY LATEST BLOG</p>
      <p>TRAVEL TO THE</p>
      <h1>Mornington Peninsula</h1>
    </div></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 

<div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>


<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>



<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> 






<p><a href="javascript:window.location.href=parallax.js-1.5.0"></a></p>
</section>


<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">.        </script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">
</script>
<script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="/parallax.js.1.5.0"></script>

</BODY>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I suggest that you take a little time to take the [tour] and read the [ask] page. There are some rules in this site, to help for content quality and so that questions can be answered more easily. In your case, you should try to isolate the part of code where the problem comes from, instead of sharing the whole page, as it makes it harder for us to find the problem, and can also improve your code mastering skills. Good luck!

Comment: hi and thankyou, its the whole page that seems to be the problem. It opens differently on safari. Also when I load it up on Firefox or safari for the first time it is zoomed right in.

Comment: Do you have your browsers at different zooms? Are you using different browsers on different monitors?

Comment: I normally use safari for  everything, but started using Firefox when I started writing my page. Safari seems to be not reading the bootstrap code properly.

Comment: my main problem is that safari has removed my blank columns from the side of the page. the website looks totally different from Firefox to safari. Is there a way I can keep it the same over all platforms